# Is Reflection supported in .Net Core?

Tags: reflection, .net-core

I've [read that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/02/10/porting-to-net-core/) `Reflection` is not supported in `.Net Core`. Is `Reflection` totally not supported in `.Net Core`? Or it would be added soon or even the only thing is needed is to use an specific `namespace`, `extension method` or a library?

Many `.Net Framework` applications relies on `Reflection`. If it is not supported in `.Net Core` in long term, which alternative may be used?

Comment: Read the article again, or [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api/) that it links to for more details, or just google for "reflection .NET core" ;-) (hint: reflection _is_ supported, albeit their are currently minor differences in API).

Comment: Use the TypeInfo class instead.  Relying on it is not the greatest idea, it is pretty troublesome in ahead-of-time compilation scenarios.  Like it already is for .NET Native as used in Store apps.  And will likely be when CoreRT gets somewhere.  Troublesome, not unsolvable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. Many reflection-intensive libraries work just fine. There are some API differences that authors might need to adjust their code for, but it pretty much works the same. However, there are still some scenarios that might be problematic. In particular, some runtimes don't allow **emitting code/ops** at runtime - this most notably affects AOT runtimes that might be encountered on mobile devices or that might go through an "app store" review process.